# Are there plans for a spring cloud update that is compatible with spring boot 2.5?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependencies, spring-cloud

I am using both spring cloud and spring boot in my project. We are adding a feature that will require the Spring Boot 2.5 release, however the latest supported Spring Boot version supported by the [most recent Spring Cloud snapshot is 2.4.6-SNAPSHOT](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud/docs/2020.0.3-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/). Are there any plans to support spring boot version 2.5 in a new Spring Cloud update or snapshot? If so, when is that projected to be released?

Comment: The 2020.0.3 release this week will support boot 2.5, see https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/milestones?direction=asc&sort=due_date&state=open

Comment: @spencergibb thanks a bunch! I am pretty new to Spring so it is helpful to see where all this is communicated.

Comment: you can also use Hoxton.SR11 version which is latest and is compatible with spring boot 2.5.